# Mostrar e esconder conteúdo em Javascript (Menu)

Tags: javascript, menu, toggle

Bom dia Pessoal, estou com uma grande dúvida.

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="mnativo"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="conteudo">
    <nav>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

A Primeira div com a classe nave é o menu que vai ficar visível.

A segunda denominada conteudo é o que vai ficar escondido.

Vamos lá,

Preciso que no momento que eu clicar na li

```
<li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
```

A div conteudo apareça.

Poderiam me auxiliar por gentileza, não estou usando nenhum biblioteca, pretendo fazer tudo sem utilizar, pois, o projeto é pequeno, por isso queria só um javascript que fizesse isso..

Desde á agradeço a todos.

Comment: Existe algum código css pronto, Wesley?

Comment: Olá Vinícius existe sim.. mas já conseguimos resolver com a resposta do Carlinhos.. ;) muito obrigado por se dispor a ajudar... abs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Só adicionei o id submenu a `div` conteudo, iniciei com `display:none` e implementei o JavaScript.
Usando javascript puro seria assim:

```js
function acao(){
var submenu = document.getElementById('submenu');
if(submenu.style.display == 'block'){
  submenu.style.display = 'none';
}else{
  submenu.style.display = 'block';
}
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="mnativo"><a href="#">teste<i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="acao()"><i class="fa fa-home">clique aqui</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star-o">teste</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-play">teste</i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="conteudo" id="submenu" style="display:none;">
    <nav>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou perfeitamente.. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Muito obrigado a todos.... Obrigado Carlinhos

Answer (score 0):

Seria isso?

```
<script>
function menu(id)
{
    for(i=1;i<=4;i++)
    {
        var div = document.getElementById("conteudo"+i);
        if(i == id)
        {
            div.style.display = "block"
        }
        else
        {
            div.style.display = "none"
        }
    }
}
</script>
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="menu">
        <li class="mnativo"><a href="#" onclick="menu('1')"><i class="fa fa-bars">menu 1</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="menu('2')"><i class="fa fa-home">menu 2</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="menu('3')"><i class="fa fa-star-o">menu 3</i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" onclick="menu('4')"><i class="fa fa-play">menu 4</i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="conteudo1" style="display:none;">
    <nav>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="conteudo2" style="display:none;">
    <nav>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="conteudo3" style="display:none;">
    <nav>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>

<div id="conteudo4" style="display:none;">
    <nav>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Utilizando um evento de click no elemento  e mudando o style.display entre none e block você consegue fazer o que quer.

```
<div class="nav">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="mnativo"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-play"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="conteudo" class="conteudo" >
        <nav>
            <ul class="submenu">
                <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Todas</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

    <li><a id="click" href="#">Click<i class="fa fa-home"></i></a></li>

    <script text="javascript">
        (function(){
            var click = document.getElementById("click");
            click.addEventListener("click", function(){
                var conteudo = document.getElementById("conteudo");
                if( conteudo.style.display === "none")
                    conteudo.style.display = "block";
                else{
                    conteudo.style.display = "none";
                }
            })
        })();
    </script>
```

Comment: Show de bola, funcionou perfeitamente.. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Muito obrigado a todos...